# Can the scalar field and time be swapped in Kaluza-klein theory?

Tags: kaluza-klein

In the Kaluza-Klein theory the scalar field was added as a fifth dimension. Was there a specific reason to do that?
Could it also be inserted between the three dimensions and time? So, can the scalar field be considered independent of the time curvature? Would a swap between the two change anything in the formulas and in the interpretation?

Comment: *scalar field was added as a fifth dimension* I think you are mischaracterizing K-K theory. In any case, a field is not a dimension, and there is no concept of “insertion between dimensions”.

Comment: I am no expert on K-K but my understanding is that you extend GR to 5 dimensions and find that the additional components of the metric tensor act like an electromagnetic four-potential and a scalar. These new fields are not dimensions. They are reinterpretations of parts of the higher-dimensional metric field.